# Outlook message, get size of a message. JS

Tags: javascript, outlook

I can't find the property ou method to get the size of a message. I get size of attachments and length of the body. But it doesn't matches with the size indicate by exchange for the same message.
Any idea ?

Thks

Comment: what message are you talking about? what attachments, and what length, and what body? please be clear with your question.

Comment: I'm talking about a message (mail) in Outlook. I have develop an addin. I want to know what is the size of the selected message. I have write a javascript, i read how many and the size of attachments to this message. I also read the body and the length of it. But i Don't find the way to calculate the total size of the selected mail.

Comment: by size you mean in bytes?

Comment: Yes. I use Office.context.mailbox.item.attachements and Office.context.mailbox.item.body properties.